# How to match child routes based on parent route?

Tags: angular, single-page-application, angular-routing

**tl;dr: I am trying to display variable route-dependent content within a fixed frame in a single-page application.**

In my `app-routing.module.ts`, I register the following route:

```js
{path: ':outer/:inner', component: MainComponent},
```

This route is in a `routes` array, which I import as `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`.

The envisioned outlet/component structure looks like this:
[image: hierarchical outlet/component structure]

Then, in the module that exports `MainComponent`, the following routes are defined:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    outlet: 'main',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'outer1/inner1', outlet: 'content', loadChildren: () => import('@myapp/outer1/inner1').then((module) => module.Outer1Inner1Module),},
      {path: '', outlet: 'content', loadChildren: () => import('@myapp/outer2/inner1').then((module) => module.Outer2Inner1Module),},
      {path: 'outer2/inner1', outlet: 'content', loadChildren: () => import('@myapp/outer2/inner1').then((module) => module.Outer2Inner1Module),},
    ]
  }
];
```

These routes are imported using `RouterModule.forChild(routes)`.

---

Now, the problem is: **Only the child route with path `''` appears to be matched - the default component of module `Outer2Inner1` is displayed in the "content" outlet.** As far as I have understood, that is because route resolution for the child routes only takes into account the remaining route after the parent has been matched.

**However, I need to match my child routes based on the path segments from the parent routes list. How can I achieve this?**

Some things that I have already tried without success:

1. Set `pathMatch` to `'full'` on the child routes. This does not change anything.
2. Supply a custom `matcher` function in the child routes - unfortunately, it also only receives the *remaining* path segments, not all of them. So, this does not help.
3. Changed the parent path to `''`, hoping that a path like `#/outer1/inner1` would be matched by the parent path `''` plus the child path `'outer1/inner1'`, but instead an exception is thrown because the path cannot be matched.
4. Registered the three inner children paths directly in `forChild`, as the duplicate mention of `MainComponent` (once in the parent route, then again the root level of the child routes) seems fishy to me. But then, nothing can be matched at all.
5. Listed the three child routes directly within the `children` array of the parent route. But in this case, these `children` routes appear to be ignored altogether.
6. Added one route to `app-routing.module.ts` for each child path, pointing to `MainComponent`, and with a `children` array that just lists one `''` route that lazily loads the respective module into outlet "content". This changes nothing, as module Outer2Inner1 is still the only one to appear.
7. I have removed all of the other routes from `app-routing.module.ts` that could influence the resolution of `outer1` or `outer2` and just added this one route:

   ```js
   {path: '', component: MainComponent, children: [
       {path: 'outer2/inner1', outlet: 'content', component: Outer2Inner1Component},
       {path: 'outer1/inner1', outlet: 'clientArea', component: Outer1Inner1Component}
   ]},
   ```

   Now, shouldn't *this*, with all lazy loading of additional modules removed, and the routes being specified directly along with the root path, work? It doesn't seem so; now an exception is thrown, saying that URL segment `outer2/inner1` does not match any routes.
   Then, if I remove the `outlet` property in the above two child routes, route `outer2/inner1` inexplicably works again, but navigating to `outer1/inner1` does nothing; it's still only `Outer2Inner1Component` being displayed. Instead, it appears that navigation to those child routes is still entirely governed by the child routes exported from the module of `MainComponent` for some reason.

Comment: So what you are saying is that in you RootRoutingModule you route to MainComponent and do so as well in your ChildRoutingModule?

Comment: One of many problems your are facing is that ChildRoutes require the previous parts to me clearly defined if your parent route is something like :stuff/:moreStuff and you go to localhost:4200/1/2 then you reach your childRoute defined by the '' path, BUT '' cannot have any children because by definition '' means "There is nothing here" so anything following it would make the match to '' impossible

Comment: @Chund: "So what you are saying is that in you RootRoutingModule you route to MainComponent and do so as well in your ChildRoutingModule?" - note that I am by no means sure this is the right way to configure my routing. The above is just what I am observing (in the code that is already there) and what works at least to some extent (i.e. my `MainComponent` fills the screen, and its "content" area displays the default component of module "Outer2Inner1".

Comment: @Chund: "'' cannot have any children" - indeed, and I am not sure I want it to. Basically, I think I want to pick the child route depending on the parent path. Or should that be done totally differently, e.g. by declaring one parent path for each child content, each having one child route to fill the "content" area?

Comment: Hope my answer covers your questions

Comment: @Chund: Thank you - I will respond to points from the answer in individual comments to make it easier to address them.

Answer (score 0):

You have something like
app.component.html

```html
<router-outlet>
</router-outlet>
```

And in your app.module.ts you import the app.routing.module with a route of

```js
routes = [
  {path: ':outer/:inner', component: MainComponent}
]
```

Here I see problem number one: By prefixing `outer` and `inner` with `:` you declare those as variables (strings/numbers/basically anything that is not some kind of structural element) so urls like `localhost:4200/myLittlePony/home` would rout to your MainComponent and you could access both `myLittlePony` and `home` via the two variable names `outer` and `inner` which is at least highly unusual.

I would expect your route to look something like:

```js
routes = [
  {path: 'main', component: MainComponent}
]
```

so that just `localhost:4200/main` routes to your MainComponent.

Let's go from there.
In another module you define another sub.routing.module.ts.
Routes you define in here can be interpreted as following the routes you specified in the RouterModule you placed `.forRoot(...)`

Meaning if you wanted to display your `InnerComponent1` in the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` that is present in your main.component.html a possible route for that would be

```js
childRoutes = [
  {path: 'inner1', component: InnerComponent1}
]
```

assuming you provide these Routes via `.forChild(childRoutes)`.

If you want to lazy load another Module like `OuterModule2` you can just it in your app.routing.module by changing your routes array to something like:

```js
routes = [
  {path: 'main', component: MainComponent,
   children: [
     path: 'outer2', loadChildren: () => import('*yourRelativePath*')
      .then(m => m.OuterModule2)
   ]
  },
]
```

assuming InnerComponent1 as mentioned above is Part of OuterModule2 and its routes are as above you should be seeing your InnerComponent1 if you go to `.../main/outer2/inner1` in the `<router-outlet>` contained in your MainComponent.

Comment: "urls like `localhost:4200/myLittlePony/home` would rout to your `MainComponent`" - this is intentional. Our application has many modules (think > 100), and *all* of them should be displayed inside the "content" area of the `MainComponent`. `MainComponent`is kind of the fixed frame around the module-specific content. Which routes exactly - well, that's what I think I need to restrict in the child routes, maybe (?) In any case, `myLittlePony/home` might be a valid module name. So, basically, `MainComponent` should *always* be displayed (except for some special routes like `/logon`).

Comment: edited the last sentence

Comment: "`localhost:4200/main` routes to your MainComponent" - I think I see your point; as I don't want a level called `main` in the path, though, I suppose I'll have to match the empty route `''` to see `MainComponent`. Then, simplifying away everything else (in particular, the lazy loading and other such indirections) and just listing the components in the child routes, I would expect to see the correct components in the "content" area. But that's not what happens - please see my edit to the question, attempt #7 to solve this.